# Playing raw PCM held in an array with GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, pcm, ogg, vorbis

I am working in C++ with ogg/vorbis

I have an array with raw PCM data decoded from a vorbis file (.ogg). The .ogg file has been decoded using libvorbis using vorbis_synthesis_pcmout. This fills a multidimentional array with the raw PCM for each channel.

I'm sure Gstreamer is capable of reading pure PCM, I have searched for the pluginto but to no avail. I'm sure I am just overlooking something simple here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for [`appsrc`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.html) .

Answer (score 0):

A PCM file is generally stored in .wav format. SO you can use wavparse plugin to play raw PCM.